# PropertyGrid changing a generic type to a specific type

Tags: c#, reflection, types, propertygrid

so I have two objects that have two different types. The first is of type `ItemTypes` called `Type`, and the second is just a generic `Type` called `SubType`.

What'd I'd like accomplished is when I change my ItemType property, I need my `SubType` property to change to one of the many different types I have (`ConsumableSubType`, `ContainerSubType`, etc..)

Here's the code for my two properties with some annotations for property grid.

```
    [RefreshProperties(System.ComponentModel.RefreshProperties.All)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumConverter))]
    [DisplayName("Type")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ItemTypes _Type
    {
        get { return Type; }
        set
        {
            Type = value;
            //Do some logic in here to set _SubType to a different type
        }
    }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumConverter))]
    [DisplayName("Sub Type")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Type _SubType { get; set; }
```

Comment: For runtime type binding you could use type dynamic

Comment: Ok, if I change my _SubType to be dynamic, after setting the type to ConsumableSubType, is it possible to refresh the property grid and now have the property be filled in with the enum values?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type of a property at runtime. You could, however, make this an `object`, and then assign whatever you like to it.

Comment: Okay, then after doing _SubtType = typeof(ConsumableSubTypes) which is a Enum. How do I go about refreshing my Property Grid to display the new from the enum?

Comment: @WesleyPattison it's not going to work that way. The property will always be of type `object`. I think the short of it is that you can't do what you're trying to do using the property grid.